# Why is my dictionary empty when using res.send with SQL Server and express.js?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, node-mssql

I'm using `mssql` with express.js. I'm trying to set the `recordset` results into a dictionary and then returning that dictionary using `res.send` but dictionary is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I have tried:

```
app.post('/api/v1/test', async (req, res) => {
    tableNames = ["test", "test2"]

    var response = {};
    for (let index = 0; index < tableNames .length; index++) {
        const table = tableNames [index];
        let query = `SELECT * FROM ${table }`
        await queryDatabase(query , function(err, result){
            response[table ] = result.recordset;
        });
    }

    res.send(
        {
            statusCode: 200,
            data: response
        }
    );
});
```

```
function queryDatabase(query, callback) {
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query(query, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err
            callback(null, result)
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queryDatabase()` does not return a promise and thus `await` does nothing useful with it so your `for` loop does not pause waiting for the query to complete and thus you call `res.send()` before your `response` object contains the data.

You can either switch to a sql module that directly supports promises or you can modify `queryDatabase()` to support promises and then modify how it's called to use the returned promise like this:

```
app.post('/api/v1/test', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        tableNames = ["test", "test2"]

        var response = {};
        for (let table of tableNames) {
            const query = `SELECT * FROM ${table}`
            const result = await queryDatabase(query);
            response[table] = result.recordset;
        }

        res.send({ statusCode: 200, data: response });
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        res.status(500).send({ statusCode: 500, data: { error: "database error" } })
    }
});

function queryDatabase(query, callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            var request = new sql.Request();
            request.query(query, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                }
                resolve(result);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you know how this can be solved with `callbacks` instead of async/awaits?

Comment: @Stoobish - It can be solved without promises and without async/await, but it's not easy because you have a loop with an asynchronous operation in it so the loop has to be coded manually if you're not going to use `await`.  Why would you not use promises and the easier way to write this code?